# How to exactly specify the height of a navigation bar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm currently learning how to program HTML and CSS (we're talking 4 days of practicing on CodeCademy) and I have a question. I got this spec sheet for a task where they want me to make the navigation bar 69px in height exactly. The navigation bar already has some height to it, of course, as it wraps around the logo and text that's in it. So, how do I specify that I want it to be exactly 69px in height?

Screenshot here that describes what they ask of me. Thanks in advance!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUqav.png)

Comment: simply add `height: 69px` to the `navbar`, other ways is by adding `padding:` or increasing the height of the child elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope all is going good!

go to the CSS file and write this.

.navbar{
height: 69px
}

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think it would be that easy.

Comment: No Worries. I'm new to programming myself. Sometimes things are super easy but look hard haha.

Let me know if you need help with anything :)

Answer (score 0):

For setting navbar height to 69px;

Inside your CSS file , simply write

.navbar{

height: 200px; /* Just an example height*/

}